# how can i create a copy of an object in session to update without updating session?

Tags: asp.net

I am confused about how to reference objects in session, how to update, and copy.

if I create 
    MyObject obj = new Object ();
then 
    Session["object"] = obj;

```
MyObject temp = (MyObject)Session["object"];
```

If i change something on temp, will the object in session be updated?

do i need to follow changes with Session["object"] = temp
?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

In case `MyObject` is a reference-type (class) and if it is mutable (i.e. it has methods that change it's state) then you don't need to reassign the Session with it every time.

In case `MyObject` is a value-type (struct) of if it is an immutable class (like String) you will have to reassign it to the Session every time you change it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the `temp` variable back to the session. As both the `Session["object"]` and `temp` variable are pointing to the same object modifying it in `temp` will also modify it in Session.